# Multi level authentication/authorization or approvals for access/delete resource in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

I want to implement a security measure that enables any authenticated user to delete any AWS resource only on approval from any other member.

The main objective is to make sure that, if the creds are compromised, the user should not be able to delete any resource without approval.

Looking forward to get some expert advise and discussion on this.

I understand, the least access privilege and MFA, but still it is fulfilling our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not directly supported by AWS, you will have to set up a custom solution for this.

This is one possible solution:

1. Create a role with delete permissions.
2. Create a Lambda to use that role to delete a resource.
3. Implement the Lambda to only processes the delete request if the input includes at least two approvals. (This part depends on your org authentication mechanism. Could be LDAP, short term access tokens, etc)

This fulfills the two requirements you mentioned:

> a security measure that enables any authenticated user to delete any AWS resource only on approval from any other member.

The Lambda will only process the request if there is at least 2 approvals.

> if the creds are compromised, the user should not be able to delete any resource without approval.

In this design there are no credentials. The role you created can only be assumed by the Lambda. You can further improve the security by only allowing certain Users, Roles or Groups to be able to execute the Lambda.